custom OpenGL engine PBR results not as expected
I have followed the LearnOpenGL tutorial for PBR and got the attached output, while nice looking I noticed the results I see in sketchfab or UE5 are far more realistic, hence I'm trying to understand if my implementation is off or if there is just more magic performed there that my custom engine lacks.
my result vs sketchfab result
I tried to debug using renderdoc and everything seems to pass as expected, the most noticeable difference to me is that UE version is much more "metallic" but it seems I pass the metallic texture as intended.
also my engine currently does not support emissive material but other than the HUD the output seems the same.
I used this model: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/battle-damaged-sci-fi-helmet-pbr-b81008d513954189a063ff901f7abfe4
vec3 fresnelSchlick(float cosTheta, vec3 F0)
{
    return F0 + (1.0 - F0) * pow(clamp(1.0 - cosTheta, 0.0, 1.0), 5.0);
}

vec3 fresnelSchlickRoughness(float cosTheta, vec3 F0, float roughness)
{
    return F0 + (max(vec3(1.0 - roughness), F0) - F0) * pow(clamp(1.0 - cosTheta, 0.0, 1.0), 5.0);
}   

float geometrySchlickGGX(float NdotV, float roughness)
{
    float r = (roughness + 1.0);
    float k = (r*r) / 8.0;

    float num   = NdotV;
    float denom = NdotV * (1.0 - k) + k;
    
    return num / denom;
}

float geometrySmith(vec3 N, vec3 V, vec3 L, float k)
{
    float NdotV = max(0.0, dot(N, V));
    float NdotL = max(0.0, dot(N, L));
    return geometrySchlickGGX(NdotV, k) * geometrySchlickGGX(NdotL, k);
}

float distributionGGX(vec3 N, vec3 H, float a)
{
    float a2 = a * a;
    float NdotH = max(0.0, dot(N, H));
    float NdotH2 = NdotH * NdotH;

    float nom = a2;
    float denom = NdotH2 * (a2 - 1.0) + 1.0;
    denom = denom * denom * PI;

    return nom / denom;
}

struct Surface
{
    vec3 fragPos;
    vec3 V;
    vec3 N;
    vec3 H;
    vec3 L;
    vec3 F0;
    vec3 albedo;
    float metallic;
    float roughness;
    
};

vec3 calculateBRDF(Surface s)
{
    // Calculate BRDF
    // Calculate Fresnel Schlick 
    vec3 F = fresnelSchlick(max(0.0, dot(s.H, s.V)), s.F0);

    vec3 ks = F;
    vec3 kd = 1.0 - ks;
    kd *= 1.0 - s.metallic;

    // Calculate NDF
    float NDF = distributionGGX(s.N, s.H, s.roughness);

    // Calculate Schlick-GGX
    float G = geometrySmith(s.N, s.V, s.L, s.roughness);

    vec3 numerator = NDF * G * F;
    float denominator = 4.0 * max(0.0, dot(s.N, s.V)) * max(0.0, dot(s.N, s.L)) + 0.0001;
    vec3 specular = numerator / denominator;

    return (specular + kd * s.albedo / PI);
}

vec3 PointLightRadiance(PointLight pLight, Surface s)
{
    s.L = normalize(pLight.position.rgb - s.fragPos); // from frag pos to light pos
    s.H = normalize(s.V + s.L);

    // Calculate Li
    float distance = length(s.L);
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (distance * distance);
    vec3 radiance = pLight.color.rgb * attenuation;

    // Calculate cosTheta
    float cosTheta = max(0.0, dot(s.N, s.L));

    return calculateBRDF(s) * radiance * cosTheta;
}

vec3 DirLightRadiance(DirLight dLight, Surface s)
{
    s.L = normalize(-dLight.direction.xyz);
    s.H = normalize(s.V + s.L);

    // Calculate Li
    vec3 radiance = dLight.color.rgb;

    // Calculate cosTheta
    float cosTheta = max(0.0, dot(s.N, s.L));

    return calculateBRDF(s) * radiance * cosTheta;
}

float shadowCalculations(vec4 fragPos)
{
    // perform perspective divide
    vec3 projCoords = fragPos.xyz / fragPos.w;
    
    vec2 texelSize = 1.0 / textureSize(gShadowMap, 0);
    
    projCoords = projCoords * 0.5 + 0.5; 
    
    float borderBias =  max(texelSize.x, texelSize.y) * 2;
    
    if(projCoords.x >= 1.0 - borderBias || projCoords.x <= borderBias ||
        projCoords.y >= 1.0 - borderBias || projCoords.y <= borderBias ||
        projCoords.z >= 1.0 - borderBias || projCoords.z <= borderBias)
        return 0.0;
    
    float shadow = 0;
    float bias = 0.005;
    float currentDepth = projCoords.z;
    
    
    for(int x = -1; x <= 1; ++x)
    {
        for(int y = -1; y <= 1; ++y)
        {
            float pcfDepth = texture(gShadowMap, projCoords.xy + vec2(x, y) * texelSize).r;
            shadow += (currentDepth - bias > pcfDepth) ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        }
    }
    
    shadow /= 9.0;
    
    return shadow;
}

void main() 
{ 
    // retrieve data from G-buffer
    vec3 fragPos = texture(gPosition, TexCoords).rgb;
    vec3 normal = texture(gNormal, TexCoords).rgb;
    vec3 albedo = pow(texture(gAlbedo, TexCoords).rgb, vec3(2.2));
    float metallic = texture(gMRA, TexCoords).r;
    float roughness = texture(gMRA, TexCoords).g;
    float ao = texture(gMRA, TexCoords).b;

    vec4 fragPosInLightSpace = lightSpaceMatrix * vec4(fragPos, 1.f);
    float shadow = shadowCalculations(fragPosInLightSpace);

    vec3 F0 = vec3(0.04); // every dieltctric object has F0 = 0.04
    F0 = mix(F0, albedo, metallic);

    // Reflectance equation
    // L0(P, W0) = integral[ BRDF(P, W0, Wi, roughness) * Li(P, Wi) * cosTheta(n, Wi) * dw ]
    // BRDF = [ DFG / (4 * dot(n, w0) * dot(n, wi)) ] + Kd * albedo / PI
    vec3 N = normalize(normal);
    vec3 V = normalize(cameraPos - fragPos);
    vec3 R = reflect(-V, N);
    vec3 L0 = vec3(0.0);

    Surface s;
    s.fragPos = fragPos;
    s.V = V;
    s.N = N;
    s.F0 = F0;
    s.metallic = metallic;
    s.roughness = roughness;
    s.albedo = albedo;

    for(int i = 0; i < pointLightCount; ++i)
    {
        L0 += PointLightRadiance(pointLights[i], s);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < dirLightCount; ++i)
    {
        L0 += DirLightRadiance(dirLight[i], s) * (1.0 - shadow);
    }

    // generate Kd to accomodate only for diffuse (exclude specular)
    vec3 F = fresnelSchlickRoughness(max(0.0, dot(N, V)), F0, roughness);
    
    vec3 prefilterColor = textureLod(gPrefilterEnvMap, R, roughness * MAX_REFLECTION_LOD).rgb;
    vec2 envBRDF = texture(gBRDFIntegrationLUT, vec2(max(dot(N, V), 0.0), roughness)).rg;
    vec3 specular = prefilterColor * (envBRDF.x * F + envBRDF.y); 

    vec3 ks = F;
    vec3 kd = 1.0 - ks;

    // ambient diffuse irradiance
    vec3 irradiance = texture(gIrradianceMap, N).rgb;
    vec3 diffuse = irradiance * albedo;
    vec3 ambient = (kd * diffuse + specular) * ao * vec3(1.f);

    // combine results
    vec3 color = L0 + ambient;

    // HDR
    color = color / (color + vec3(1.0));

    // Gamma correction
    color = pow(color, vec3(1.0/2.2));

#ifdef CUSTOM_SHADER
    frag(color);
#endif
    
    FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
} 


One thing I see that's wrong here is how you apply fresnel. It should be applied to each light and be calculated using the half vector, instead of calculated once using N dot V. Search for "fresnel" here: https://learnopengl.com/PBR/Lighting

To whomever crosses this path,
after some investigation my mistake was actually not in the shader at all,
I loaded an LDR (Low dynamic range) texture as the skybox, which created a blend irradiance map (light has less variance -> less variance in the generated texture), so the fix was to to add proper HDR support and load an HDR texture as the skybox.
results (still not perfect as the AO looks a bit wierd but certainly more "metallic" looking which was what I thought lack):
result
